# Setting up relationships for like system in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4, table-relationships

I was making a simple project to practice with Laravel, but I'm stuck. I can't figure out why anytime I click on the `like` button, a new row in my table is created... so I have "multiple rows (1)" for any click to the like button I make.

multiple rows (1)
[image]

I suspect this has something to do with relationships between my models, but I can't see what I'm making wrong.

My **User.php** Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait;

class User extends \Eloquent implements Authenticatable
{
    use AuthenticableTrait;

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
    }
}
```

My **Memo.php** Model

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Memo extends Model
{
    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
    }
}
```

My **Like.php** Model

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Like extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function memo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Memo');
    }
}
```

My **MemoController** method where i handle my AJAX request:

```
public function likeMemo(Request $request)
{
    $memo_ID = $request['id'];
    $memo = Memo::findOrFail($memo_ID)->first();

    // Is already liked...?
    $like = Auth::user()->likes()->where('memo_id', $memo_ID)->first();

    if($like->is_like) {
        $like->is_like = false;
        $like->update();
        return response()->json(['status' => $like], 200);
    }

    // Insert data into DB.
    else {
        $like = new Like();
        $like->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $like->memo_id = $memo_ID;
        $like->is_like = true;
        $like->save();
        return response()->json(['status' => 'inserted like']);
    }

}
```

The code, should be able to toggle the like in a specific memo, like Instagram since my goal is to make the logic to add those memos in a specific **Favourites** category.

Comment: add the code where you insert data in table

Comment: @devnullΨ i didn't added it because i don't thing it has anything to do with my problem, of course i can be wrong.  

[This](https://pastebin.com/7wkmZmvg) is the controller method where i handle my AJAX request, i'm just having a bad time trying to insert the code manually here.

Comment: please next time add the code to your question by updating it. in your code if data is not liked, you insert a new record, so each time if data is not liked it will insert a new record with different id. my wild guess is that if record doesn't exist, you should create it, but if its not like you should only update it, like you do in first condition

Comment: @devnullΨ i'm sorry, i'll make future questions as clear as possible, really new this platform. It seems like this was the problem, i'll try your solution by updating existing values and saving the new ones, then i'll let you know if it works.

Comment: I added the code, try it in that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you should update your data if its not liked, and create a new one only if you couldn't find record.

```
 public function likeMemo(Request $request)
{
    $memo_ID = $request['id'];
    $memo = Memo::findOrFail($memo_ID)->first();

    // Is already liked...?
    $like = Auth::user()->likes()->where('memo_id', $memo_ID)->first();

     // Insert data into DB.
    if(!$like) {
        $like = new Like();
        $like->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $like->memo_id = $memo_ID;
        $like->is_like = true;
        $like->save();
        return response()->json(['status' => 'inserted like']);
    } else {

       if($like->is_like) {
           $like->is_like = false;
           $like->update();
           return response()->json(['status' => $like], 200);
       } else {
           $like->is_like = true;
           $like->update();
           return response()->json(['status' => $like], 200);
      }  
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver. BTW, i just edited my question to allow other users get benefit from this thread. Thank you very much for your help!